# Best way of PHP with Oracle?

Tags: php, oracle

I'm just new with Oracle. But i wanna test with PHP. Which way or method should i use is the best?

I've found following various ways by googling yet,

- The oci8 extension
- The oracle extension
- PEAR DB library
- ADOdb library
- Zend
- or otherelse?

Actually i don't know know about these and which one is best.

Comment: `oci8` would be the definitive answer as most other tools would merely be wrappers around this. `PDO_Oci` is also an option but as mentioned below, still marked experimental.

Comment: Thanks Phil. With `oci8` i need an `Instant Client` from Oracle, rite? Is there another additional requirement? :)

Comment: What is it you'd like to "test"?  If you're looking for a OO db abstraction layer, you might look into MDB2 (merge of Pear DB and Metabase).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately PDO support is still considered experimental.

I've not read it, since I have no interest in oracle these days, but you might check out [this oracle publication](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html) which I have not read.

Comment: The most recommended option is "oci8" bro. I wanna dig about it.